# Integate Google Drive with React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-drive-api

I want to integrate Google Drive with my React project to get files. Since I'm getting files from local and convert the files into base64 and save to backend,
now I have to get the files from Google Drive I use `google-drive-picker` for the integration on the front-end.

I want that I can download the fileurl as a PDF which is coming in the response and convert the PDF into base64. How can I do this?

I want to download this link directly or do i need any help from the backend?

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import useDrivePicker from "react-google-drive-picker";

function UploadFromGoogle() {
  const [openPicker, authResponse] = useDrivePicker();
  const handleOpenPicker = () => {
    openPicker({
      clientId: "eo9uk...dkepvj3t.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      developerKey: "AIzaSyA7lfMNQhE...uk",
      viewId: "DOCS",
      showUploadView: true,
      showUploadFolders: true,
      supportDrives: true,
      multiselect: true,
      callbackFunction: (data) => {
        if (data.action === "cancel") {
          console.log("User clicked cancel/close button");
        }
        console.log("===>>>>", data.docs[0]);
      },
    });
  };
  return ( 
    <div><button onClick={() => handleOpenPicker()}>Upload File from Drive</button></div>  
  );
}
```